# class 'form' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have followed these steps as answered in similar questions here but, i don't get a solution:

1. edited `composer.json` to add:

   `"require": {
           "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
       }`
2. update composer from terminal:

   `composer update`
3. Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

`'providers' => [
        // ...
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        // ...
      ],`

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

the error is:

> FatalErrorException in 94130ac18d8152bd785794934f1ccfb5f9a84201.php
>   line 18: Class 'Form' not found

the view file is `index.blade.php`

```
@section('main')

<h1>All Users</h1>

<p><a href={{ url('users\create') }}>Add new user</a></p>

@if ($users->count())
    <table border="2">
<tr><td>s.n.</td><td>name</td><td>email</td><td>options</td>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
           <tr>
<td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                    <td><a href={{ url('users\{id}\edit', $user->id)}}>Edit</a>

<td>
          {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 
        'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id))) }}                       
                            {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    </td>                
</tr>
      @endforeach


    </table>
@else
    There are no users
@endif

@stop
```

Comment: You can also try to wipeout the vendor dir and do `composer install`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47056600/4701635

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

Also, try to use `{!! Form:: !!}` instead of `{{ Form:: }}` everywhere.

Comment: Try to use {!! Form:: !!} instead of {{ Form:: }} everywhere.

Comment: Did you change all `{{ Form }}` elements in a view?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by using the following steps.

Steps:

1) Open composer.json file and add the following line to the require.

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
```

So it looks like:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "intervention/image": "dev-master"
},
```

2) Now run composer update command to get the package.

```
composer update
```

2) Open App/config/app.php file and add the following line to the providers and aliases array.

To the providers array:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

To the aliases array:

```
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

See more: http://www.pranms.com/laravel-5-2-form-class-not-found/

Comment: You missed the heart of answer, Add one more line to remove above error ‘Form’ => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,

Answer (score 0):

HTML and FORM helper is removed form Laravel 5 and above
but still, you can use it in your Latest Laravel.

First, install laravelcollective/html using composer in your project folder using Command prompt:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

add the following lines inside **config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],
```

and,

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
   'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
   'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
// ...
],
```

Answer (score -1):

//This is composer file simply copy paste this whole code in the same file
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
         "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"

```
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

//This is app.php whole code simply copy paste this code in your file

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
| running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
| services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
|
*/

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Fallback Locale
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
| is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
| the language folders that are provided through your application.
|
*/

'fallback_locale' => 'en',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logging Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
|
*/

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoloaded Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
| request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
| this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
|
*/

'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,


    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,


],
```

];