# Class ' Form' not found in view-file.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

I'm trying to render a text input field in my view file. 
I keep getting this error: "Class 'form' not found in view-file.blade.php"

Template:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>New</h1>

    {{ Form::open() }}
        {{ Form::text('my-name') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endsection
```

Composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5.0"
},
```

app.php (config)

```
'providers' => [
    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,

    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    /*
     * Laravel Framework aliases...
     */
    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    /*
     * Packages aliases...
     */
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],
```

'Composer show' lists the following:

```
laravel/framework v5.5.19 The Laravel Framework
laravelcollective/html v5.5.1  HTML and Form Builders for the Laravel Framework
```

I've already tried some things that were suggested in other SO questions like:

- composer dump-auto
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear

Still not working. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once visit this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-form-not-found)

Comment: The first thing I would start assuming you are using Laravel 5.5 as you tagged your question is using 5.5 of `laravelcollective/html`

Comment: @rahulsm I did exactly what that link says

Comment: @Marcin Nabialek: Yes, ‘composer show’ says that I’m using the 5.5 version of laravelcollective/html

Answer (score 15):

**Install laravelcollective/html**

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.5"
```

**Update Composer**

```
composer update
```

**Add Provider and Static Facade in `config/app.php`**

```
<?php

'providers' => [

    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

  ],

'aliases' => [

      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,

      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’ve checked which version of the laravelcollective package is installed and it’s the 5.5 one. So, I would think that I’m good to go but still getting the error :(

Comment: First Download directly from https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html and put in vendor\laravelcollective folder after adding in composer.json

Comment: I've edited my original question. I've updated the package version in composer.json (although I already had 5.5.1 of laravel collective) I also added the output of 'composer show' for the laravel framework & laravel collective packages. I've checked if the classes exist (to which the aliases point to) and they do! So still no clue here :(

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to adding it into config/app before Composer was done installing it.

Try using `php artisan config:cache`